# Coaster brake question

Tags: brakes, coaster

I have recently bought a bike with a coaster brake. After over 50 years of cycling with brakes on both handlebars I am finding it difficult. Is it possible to change a coaster brake for a conventional back brake on the handlebar?

Noreen

Comment: More practical is to add rim brakes (assuming the frame and rims are reasonably compatible).  No need to disable the coaster brake.

Comment: Do you want to just add a handbrake, or disable the coaster brake as well ?

Comment: Embrace the coaster brake. They are fun. Lay down some mad-skidddz.

Comment: @DanielRHicks “no need to disable the coaster brake” – well, except to _get rid of that horrible back-ratcheting preventer_!

Answer (score 7):

You can’t actuate a coaster brake with a brake leaver/cable, if that’s what you are asking.

You’ll have to install a normal, hand actuated brake and brake lever.

Apart from coaster brakes there are generally two types of brakes: Rim brakes and disc brakes. For rim brakes your frame will need rim brake mounting points and your wheel needs a rim with braking surface. For disc brakes you need a frame with disc brake mounting points and your wheel needs a disc brake hub.

For brakes with cables (i.e. not hydraulic), cable stops welded to the frame would be nice but a continuous cable housing works as well.

It’s quite likely your frame has mounting points for rim brakes. If you are lucky your wheel also has a rim with braking surfaces.